# Creating an animated bar graph with R

Tags: r

Here's the example I'm trying to emulate, but I don't even need to use the tweenr library in my use case :

https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/288-animated-barplot-transition/

I cannot figure out how to use ggplot to make a proper bar graph using the data frame from my CSV.

---

My dataset is a CSV file that looks something like this:

```
Year,LabelOne,LabelTwo,LabelThree

87-88,15160,3190,1590

88-89,16530,3260,1650

89-90,17050,3340,1650
```

I'm using

```
df <- read.table("~/Downloads/data.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
```

But that's where I get stuck, I'm trying to make an animated bar graph, but I can't even make a static one. The idea is that each row in the dataset is one frame in the final GIF. (Lables as labels, and the values are the heights of each corresponding bar and column 1 being used as the title for each bar graph.)

For ex. Frame one should have 3 bar graphs side by side, with "LabelOne" having a height of 15160, "LabelTwo" having a height of 3190, etc. And a title of "87-88".

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What is your code? What are you "stuck" on? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your data:

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
         Year = c("87-88", "88-89", "89-90"),
     LabelOne = c(15160L, 16530L, 17050L),
     LabelTwo = c(3190L, 3260L, 3340L),
   LabelThree = c(1590L, 1650L, 1650L)
)
```

The first step is converting to long format:

```
library(tidyr)
df_long <- gather(df, lbs, Value, LabelOne:LabelThree, -Year)
```

It will look like this:

```
   Year     lbs    Value
1 87-88   LabelOne 15160
2 88-89   LabelOne 16530
3 89-90   LabelOne 17050
4 87-88   LabelTwo  3190
5 88-89   LabelTwo  3260
6 89-90   LabelTwo  3340
7 87-88 LabelThree  1590
8 88-89 LabelThree  1650
9 89-90 LabelThree  1650
```

Then use `ggplot` to create a bargraph:

```
ggplot(df_long[df_long$Year=="87-88",], 
 aes(x = lbs, y = Value, fill = lbs)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

To automate the process:

```
library(dplyr)
df_long %>% group_by(Year) %>% do(plots = ggplot(data = .) + 
 aes(x = lbs, y = Value, fill = lbs) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
 ggtitle(unique(.$Year))) -> plots
```

Comment: Thanks! I still get this error when I try your code, I think I did everything correct:


`> ggplot(df[df$Year=="87-88",], 
+        aes(x = labels, y = values, fill = labels)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.

Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 3`

Comment: That's because I was silly and made one of the variable names `Labels` which is the name of function. I've corrected my answer and changed it to `lbs. Please remember to mark this as answer if it works for you.

Comment: Fantastic! Is there anyway to make the automation work with gganimate w/o using dplyr?

https://github.com/dgrtwo/gganimate

Thanks!

Comment: No idea, I haven't used gganimate.